# Compilation Error in C: request for member ‘____’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct, compilation, pthreads, cpu-architecture

I am getting the following compilation error: `request for member ‘threeds’ in something not a structure or union`

here is my struct:

```
struct pthread_arg {
int size;
int threeds;
int the_threads;

};
```

Here is the line causing the issue:

```
    int first = *(arg.threeds) * N/number_of_the_threads;
```

I have looked at other similar questions on here, but still got the same error after making the changes suggested.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the variable `arg`.

Comment: `void *multiplication(void *arg)` is the function

Comment: How `void*` can have members?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. `arg` is a pointer to void, not a struct. Compiler tells you so. You do use it like a struct. What is unclear about that? It is not even a pointer to struct (as I wrongly guessed in my deleted comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears `arg` is an arugment passed to a thread function (which is a pointer to your struct).

In that case, you can't directly dereference `arg` because it's a `void*`. Convert it to appropriate type (which must match the argument passed to pthread_create API) and then use:

```
void *multiplication(void *arg)
{
    struct pthread_arg *myarg = arg;
    int first = myarg->threeds * N/number_of_the_threads;
    ...
```